# How can I fix this strange box model behaviour of Webkit browsers?

Tags: html, webkit, margin, css

I came across a very strange behaviour of Webkit browsers today: It concerns the way a margin is calculated next to other (floated) blocks.
Though I think this must be a common problem, I couldn't find anything about it so far.

Here's my situation: I have two `<aside>`s followed by a `<div>`. They are all displayed next to each other, the `<div>` on the left then `.#aside-1` and `#aside-2`. I achieve this throught the following CSS code:

```
aside {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

#aside-1 {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

#aside-2 {
  float: right;
}

div {
  overflow: auto;    /* Block formatting context */

  margin-right: 400px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
}
```

This works fine in Firefox and IE>6.
However, what happens in Chrome and Safari is that the `margin-right` of the `div` isn't calculated from the right boundary, but is instead only calculated from the left of `aside-2`. This causes the `div` to be 200 pixels (width + padding of `sidebar-2`) too small.

What causes this Webkit behaviour and how can I fix it?
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help in advance!

---

OK, so I tested a bit more and came up with a simple solution):

Just give the `div` a fixed width. This of course only works if your layout is based on fixed widths, which is the case for me.

Comment: Without a link or the complete markup, anything we say is just a wild guess. However, your comments show you must be misunderstanding something. In no way can any version of IE understand anything related to HTML5 without some javascript help. Also, even earlier versions of Firefox need some CSS help. So I believe Chrome is displaying what you wrote and you are looking at other browsers as a reference.

Comment: This thing is resolved for me now, but since I still don't understand the effect, feel free to discuss a bit on!

1. I unfortunately can't share a link right now, but from what I've tested the bug should be visible as well if you just create a mininmal HTML document with the free elements and my CSS source and look at it using Webkit Inspector.

2. IE9 could indeed, for earlier version I use a simple JS fix.

3. I'm referring to Firefox>=4 here, but the correct display should be the case for prior versions as well.

Comment: You're not going to get any responses if you want us to do the work. That's what jsfiddle is for. For you to create test cases. In any case, never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always, always use a modern browser (anything but IE).

Comment: OK well, take a look at this then: http://jsfiddle.net/7BzK3/2/ I expect the blue box to touch the yellow one. That's also what happens in FF, Opera and even IE9 (I'm not saying that IE always does things right but that's a fact). In Webkit browsers however, there is a 200px gap because the margin of the blue box is only caldulated from the left border of the green one.

Comment: It is behaving differently but I'm not sure what's going on (too early and leaving town). The W3C spec says 'overflow:auto' is user agent dependent and not specified. You may need to do some Googling on this one. Removing overflow causes Chrome to act the same as the others.

Comment: You're right, but the point here isn't that `overflow: auto` isn't specified – it's the Block formatting context of the `div`: The same problem is present as well with `overflow: hidden`. You can find some descriptions of similar issues online, [this one](http://marquex.es/438/overflow-hidden-chrome-against-the-rest-of-browsers) having exactly the same situation. There doesn't seem to be a common fix; [this Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19123) might be related but deals with another problem in particular. Anyway, thanks for clarifying a bit more!

Answer (score -1):

Try with CSS RESET, that should work.
Here's one : http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: I already use [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in my complete layout.

However, I also tried the one you suggested and it unfortunately didn't work as well.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding position:relative; to your <aside> elements, and then with left or right to move your elements (the point is to eliminate the margins)...

Comment: That would work. However, it's not the solution I'd prefer and I stukk don't see why Webkit behaves that way with margins.